# Requerimento para o gerador android na versão X Ev3 do GeneXus

Tags: java, android, sdk, genexus

Estou usando o atualmente o GeneXus X Ev2 U5.
Gostaria de fazer uns testes com a versão X Ev3.
O que preciso instalar de novo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão Evolution 3 não tem requisitos adicionais.

A única coisa que muda é a API do Android. Na Evolution 2 é necessária a API 15, na Evolution 3 é a API 19.

[Saiba mais](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?14449)